# eloquent javascript correlation tableFor explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, eloquent

I am taking my first steps in programming and i am stuck with this problem from eloquent, in particular with the weresquirrel problem. Here it goes  :

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
 return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
   for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
     var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
      if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
      if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
      table[index] += 1;
 }
 return table;
}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
// → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

I do understand the first function hasevent, it returns true if an entry contains a given event.

what i can't grasp is the tableFor function. I can't get how the function flows and HOW the table gets its values. For example for console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL)); , we get [76, 9, 4, 1]. But How for god's sake ?

The journal is supplied by the book and looks like this :

```
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events":["pizza","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched 
  tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed 
  teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed 
  teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","candy","brushed 
  teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed 
  teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched 
  tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","beer","brushed 
  teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","nachos","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","brushed 
   teeth","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","nachos","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false} ...etc
```

What i understand is that an event is passed as a parameter and it looks through the array of objects in Jounral to see if it's present. But how does the counting take place ?

```
if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
```

Why is this +2 ? why not index += 3; or index += 4; ???

and finally why table[index] += 1; ???

For example the first loop goes like this, for  : 
    console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));

```
//FLOW
i=0;
```

from the first line above in journal, pizza is present.

```
     if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
```

so index is incremented and becomes 1.it continues to :

```
     if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
```

squirel is false, so nothing happens to index.If squirel were to be found, why is it +2 ???

then
          table[index] += 1
i can't understand from this point.

Can someone please break it down for me ? It would be very helpful for my training.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `table` array is a count of entries that meet different criteria. `table[3]` is the count of entries where both `entry.squirrel` are `hasEvent(event, entry)` are true. `table[2]` is the count where just `entry.squirrel` is true, `table[1]` is the count where just `hasEvent(event, entry)` is true, and `table[0]` is the count where neither is true.

So the logic is that `index` starts at `0`. If `hasEvent(event, entry)` is true, we add `1` to it. If `entry.squirrel` is true we add `2` to it. The result is that if both are true, we end up adding `3`. And if neither is true we don't add anything, so it's still `0`.

Then we add `1` to `table[index]` to increment that counter.

Comment: After putting a lot of console log and READING your answer, i finally get to understand behind this logic. But how did he come up with the logic of placing each index increment in the right case ? for example if there were five elements in our table array, we would have put table[index] += 3 then ?Thanks a lot answering, i can now sleep quite in peace..

Comment: It's actually binary. Each bit in the index corresponds to one of the criteria, and adding powers of 2 is equivalent to setting bits in the binary representation of the index. If there were more criteria, they would use `index += 4;`, and `index += 8`.

Comment: The size of the `table` array is 2**n, where n is the number of criteria, because that's the number of different combinations of criteria.

Answer (score 0):

1. About JOURNAL :: Each entry has list of **events** and **become
   squirrel?** bool value.
2. About CODE ::

input --> event ( one of  `[beer, bread, brushed teeth, brussel sprouts, candy, carrot, cauliflower, computer, cycling, dentist, exercise, ice cream, lasagna, lettuce, nachos, peanuts, pizza, potatoes, pudding, reading, running, spaghetti, television, touched tree, weekend, work]`).

output --> table(1 X 4)

```
table[0] -- Number of entries in JOURNAL which does not has given event and  squirrel is False.
table[1] -- Number of entries in JOURNAL which has given event and  squirrel is False.
table[2] -- Number of entries in JOURNAL which does not has given event and  squirrel is True.
table[3] -- Number of entries in JOURNAL which has given event and  squirrel is True.
```

```
**hasEvent(event, entry)  entry.squirrel  table[index]** 
False                   False           table[0] += 1
True                    False           table[1] += 1
False                   True            table[2] += 1
True                    True            table[3] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through this same book and I came across this discussion and thought I could contribute as well. I'm a beginner as well so please correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway, this is how I understand it:

First, we call the function `tableFor`with two parameters `"pizza"` (a string; one of the possible causes for Jacques to turn into a squirrel we have to check) and `JOURNAL`(an object; it consists of the following properties: `"events"` - possible causes - and `"squirrel"` - whether Jacques turned into a squirrel that day or not). The `JOURNAL` itself is an array consisting of multiple objects. Also, the `"events"`property is an array as well.

The two parameters `"pizza"` and `JOURNAL` are then passed to the `tableFor` parameters `event` and `journal`, so now `"pizza"` is `event` and `JOURNAL` is `journal`.

Since the end result has to be an array consisting of 4 elements so we could calculate the correlation later, we declare a variable to store this array:
`var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];`Then we have to figure a way to make the values of the array to increment themselves when needed: `for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++)` which means we are making a loop to go through every element of the `journal`. `i = 0` means we're currently looking for `"pizza"` in the 1st element of the `journal` array and then move on the the 2nd one. 3rd one etc. until the last element of the array, hence `i < journal.length`.

`var entry = journal[i], index = 0;` means that we take the n-th element of the array and assign it to the `entry` variable, and define `index` (the current index in the `table` array) as 0.

Here we call another function `hasEvent`:

```
<pre>if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;</pre>

<pre>function hasEvent(event, entry) {
return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}</pre>
```

which means we take the `event` (`"pizza"`) and the `entry` the 0th element of `journal` array and check whether it contains the key word `"pizza"`. If it doesn't contain it `indexOf` willll return -1, if it does it'll return the first index at which the given element is present. In our 1st case, `{"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false}`, there's no `"pizza"`, so `indexOf` will return -1. This line `if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;` asks whether hasEvent is true (whether `indexOf` is not equal -1). In our case it is equal -1, so we don't add 1 to `index`. And this line `if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;` asks whether it's true that Jacques has turned into a squirrel (we can see that it's false), so we don't add 2 to `index`. So our current index we're working with remains at 0. And now we increase it by 1 (`table[index] += 1;`), so in the very first scenario we have the following result [1, 0, 0, 0].

It's also worth mentioning that in our `table` array:

```
`index 0 = 00 (no pizza, no squirrel)
index 1 = 10 (pizza, no squirrel)
index 2 = 01 (no pizza, squirrel)
index 3 = 11 (pizza, squirrel)`
```

So depending on each case, we'll move from index 0 to index 1,2,3 or stay at index 0 and increase it by one depending on which conditions are met. 
I hope someone finds my explanation/understanding useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused with the following:

```
if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;
```

```
if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
```

```
table[index] += 1;
```

This actually means: if 
`(entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;` === `true`, add 1 to index. In that case, we can translate it as `table[1] += 1`

And if below is true as well,

```
if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
```

then:
`table[3] += 1`

`table[3]`is populated only if `squirrel` and `entry`=== `true`

`if (entry.squirrel) index += 2`is increased by 2 because `squirrel`is true in `table[2]`.

`table[index]` is actually just an index we want to use as a target.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this explanation**

Listen. I believe that table=[0,0,0,0]; for the sake of this answer, I have represented the table as [Whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever] instead of the zeros.

This for loop will access every element inside the arrays of entries one element at a time, from one array of entry to the next array, from day 1 to the last day of the Jacques's experiences record. **for(let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++){**

This next step, makes the elements more accessible by making a simple variable(binding, etc) called entry(it could have had any variable name but it is called entry). i.e, **let entry = journal[i], index = 0;** entry will be each element inside the Journal. index=0, This index belongs to table.

Each time the table[index] updates that is by adding 1, index = 0 also adds 1. This will happen to table =[+1, whatever, whatever, whatever] or [1, 0, 0, 0]

except it sees the event (pizza), i.e **if (entry.events. includes(event)), index+=1;** then table[index] adds 1 to the second zero. This will happen to table= [Whatever, +1, whatever, whatever] or [0, +1, 0, 0]

when it sees squirrel as true, table[index] adds 1 to the third zero, instead of doing the previous two steps. **if (entry.squirrwl), index+= 2;** Table will look like this [whatever, whatever, +1, whatever]

Now check this out, **if(entry.events.includes(event)),index+= 1;
if(entry.squirrel) index+= 2**
when it sees both event and squirrel, that is if both are pizza and squirell are present together, what happens? Because of the double if, table[index] updates the fourth zero in table, i.e event +=1, squirrel += 2 = +3. So table[index] adds 1 to the fourth and last zero, i.e the 3rd index of table= [0,0,0,adds 1] or [whatever, whatever, whatever, +1]

This happens because, the situation is different, here it saw both squirrel and the event. Previously it either saw

- neither squirrel nor the event[adds+1,0,0,0],
- or it saw the event alone[0,adds+1,0,0],
- or squirrel alone[0,0,adds+1,0],
- now it sees both event and squirrel[0,0,0,adds+1] that is the power of double if.

I am not perfect at this or its syntaxes, but please I would love to Hear comments if it was wrong or make corrections. So take note of how to use such loops that loop over a data set entry and has an array in the function to update certain info, take note of the Index and how if statements make them to update the array in the function.