# How does filling array works with for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to learn from eloquentjavascript, but now I'm just stuck, because I can't figure out how code from example works.

This is in chapter 4, first function to count corelation from JOURNAL file:

```
function hasEvent(event, entry){
return entry.events.indexOf(event) !=-1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal){
  var table =[0,0,0,0]; 
  for (var i=0; i<journal.length;i++){ 
    var entry = journal [i], index=0; 
    if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index++;
    if (entry.squirrel) index +=2;
    table[index]+=1; 

 }
  return table;


}
console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
//[76,9,4,1]
```

I dont understand construction of for, especially filling and adding indexes. How does it counts? Why it isn't index = 0, index = 1, index = 2, index=3?

Comment: The `for` loop is incrementing `i`, not `index`. `index` is updated by `index++` and `index += 2` in the `if` statements.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong in your calling code. Inside `tableFor()`, `journal` will be `undefined`.

Comment: I posted an answer about this exact same exercise here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697619/eloquent-javascript-correlation-tablefor-explanation/45697755#45697755